# How to retrieve the total count

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

This is an Stored Procedure running in SQL Server. I also want to bring out the total count of the returned data.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spManufacturerdata]
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT [t1].[OEMName] AS [oem], [t1].[OemId] AS [id]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[OEMName], [t0].[OemId]
    FROM [dbo].[tblOEM] AS [t0]
    WHERE [t0].[IsActive] = 1
    ) AS [t1]
order BY LOWER([t1].[OEMName])

END
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.  I'm not sure what "total count of returned data" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Can't you simply check the rowcount on the calling side?

Answer (score 0):

Add **Group By**:

```
SELECT COUNT([t1].[OemId]) AS TotalCount,[t1].[OEMName] AS [oem], [t1].[OemId] AS [id]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[OEMName], [t0].[OemId]
    FROM [dbo].[tblOEM] AS [t0]
    WHERE [t0].[IsActive] = 1
    ) AS [t1]
GROUP BY [t1].[OEMName] , [t1].[OemId] 
order BY LOWER([t1].[OEMName])
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that a `COUNT()` or `COUNT(DISTINCT)` would just return 1 for each row.

If you want the total count over all the rows, then you want something like this:

```
SELECT t.OEMName as oem, t.OemId as id,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as total_rows,
       COUNT(*) OVER () as total_combinations
FROM dbo.tblOEM t
WHERE t.IsActive = 1
GROUP BY t.OEMName, t.OemId
ORDER BY LOWER(t.OEMName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have understood you.
If you want to count the total records returned by previous select, you just need to call count():

```
SELECT COUNT([t1].[OEMName]) AS totalRowsInPreviuosQuery
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[OEMName], [t0].[OemId]
    FROM [dbo].[tblOEM] AS [t0]
    WHERE [t0].[IsActive] = 1
) AS [t1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT count(*) AS TotalCount
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[OEMName]
        ,[t0].[OemId]
    FROM [dbo].[tblOEM] AS [t0]
    WHERE [t0].[IsActive] = 1
    ) AS [t1]
```